# Единицы измерения rem и px

Tags: css3, вёрстка, css

Доброго времени суток. Я несколько дней пытаюсь найти ответ на свой вопрос. Решила обратиться к вам. Хотелось бы начать пользоваться при верстке такими единицами, как `rem`, но нигде нет информации, как и где их применять. В основном информация одна и та же. Я знаю, что не только `Rem`, но и `px`. Как их правильно использовать вместе? Может, вы знаете какую-то статью или сами верстаете. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Крайне рекомендую ознакомиться со следующей статьей:

**[Font Size Idea: px at the Root, rem for Components, em for Text Elements](http://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/)**

В ней есть очень наглядный пример использования этих значений.

Еще полезно будет почитать вот эту подборку:

**[Why Ems?](http://css-tricks.com/why-ems/)**
**[px – em – % – pt – keyword](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)**
**[Relative is the new absolute: the rem unit](http://www.css3files.com/2012/10/11/relative-is-the-new-absolute-the-rem-unit/)**
**[Should I use px or rem in my css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-in-my-css)**

Comment: Прикольная подборка, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вот, например, эта статья: [Адаптивные размеры шрифтов при помощи REM](http://www.coolwebmasters.com/cssstyle-sheets/3771-flexible-font-sizes-with-rem.html)

> С самого зарождения интернета люди начали дискутировать на тему того, как лучше всего определять шрифты. Кроме традиционных кандидатов – вроде px, em и %, – есть еще единица измерения rem, которая представляет собой довольно новую альтернативу, совмещающую в себе лучшие свойства своих предшественников.

Comment: Я это читала... Это не то, что нужно, к сожалению... Спасибки за ответ.

Comment: И что мешает пользоваться rem?

Comment: Не знаю, как правильно использовать... После прочтения одной статьи... Напугали, что нельзя везде использовать... Нужно знать, где ставить эти единицы измерения...

Comment: Практика, еще раз практика - сделайте несколько страниц с разными единицами и сами увидите разницу. Мое мнение - для адаптивности em вполне достаточно, и поддержка браузеров выше на данный момент, чем для rem.

Comment: спасибо. попробую и вправду попрактиковаться...

Answer (score 1):

[[@kamila](/users/14767/kamila)](/users/14767/kamila), не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос: "*Как их правильно правильно использовать вместе?*"

Для себя, я это понимаю так: "**rem unit**" - это практически то же, что и "**em unit**", с той лишь разницей, что "**em**" масштабирует шрифт относительно font-свойств его ближайшего или прямого родительского элемента, а "**rem**" - всегда относительно корневого элемента. А вот "**px unit**", в отличие от них, не масштабируется.

Comment: Да, Вы правы.У них не большая разница... Я просто для себя решила, что rem будет лучше.. я имею ввиду, то что нельзя же задавать padding, margin картинкам width, height rem или em или можно?? Я читала, что не правильно везде задавать rem или em.. Сайт будет не корректно работать при увеличении или уменьшении шрифта... Поэтому я пытаюсь понять, как правильно работать с этими единицами..Хоть бы на каком то маленьком примере, что бы понять суть...

Comment: @kamila, а почему Вы так упорно хотите использовать эту единицу измерения, если даже не понимаете, в чем её преимущество? ))

Comment: Во-первых я хочу разобраться... И во - вторых нужно очень и очень  разобраться))) Между прочим я понимаю в чем ее преимущество..

Comment: @kamila, давайте [попробуем с примером][1]. Кликайте по кнопке и следите за тем, как изменяются шрифты, когда мы изменяем свойство корневого элемента. Потом измените селектор в JS:

    // вместо
    $('html').css('font-size', sizes[i++] + '%');
    // ставим
    $('p').css('font-size', sizes[i++] + '%');

Разницу, я так думаю, что почуствуете.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/39a2ty4m/1/

Comment: Ничего себе)) Вам не сложно было написать... Спасибо Вам огромное!)) Дело в то, что я это понимаю... Я не понимаю другое, когда верстаешь, в каких ситуациях использовать rem(em), а в каких (px)? Насколько я поняла, нельзя использовать на сайте одни rem(em)...

Comment: @kamila, я не могу назвать себя верстальщиком в полном смысле этого слова, но использую **px**, когда надо жёстко задать размеры, **em** - когда нужно масштабировать относительно родителя (для взаимосвязи элементов при **медиа-запросах**) и очень редко **rem**, когда нужно внутри родителя сделать что-то вроде "reset-а"(сброса).

* ... продолжение ниже ... *

Comment: То есть размеры по прежнему масштабируются, но уже не зависимо от родителя. Опять же, это если и использую, то в медиа-запросах. Если еще проще, то для мобильных устройств с маленьким экраном, задавать дочернему элементу размер шрифта меньше относительно родителя, может быть совсем не читабельно.